# Evaluate $\int _{ }^{ }\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^3}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

My attempt at solution is...

$ \int _{ }^{ }\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^3}}dx\ \left(u=x^3,\ dx=\frac{du}{3x^2}\right) $

$ \int _{ }^{ }\frac{1}{3x^2\sqrt{1+u}}du\ \ \left[\sqrt[3]{u}=x\right] $

$ \int _{ }^{ }\frac{1}{3u^{\frac{2}{3}}\sqrt{1+u}}du $

according to Wolfram this is equal to the function $ _2F_1 $

$ \int _{ }^{ }\frac{1}{3u^{\frac{2}{3}}\sqrt{1+u}}du=\sqrt[3]{u}_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2};\frac{4}{3}-u\right)+C $

I have no idea how to get to that result, what is the simplest and easiest way to understand to be able to do this type of integrals with the 2F1 function?

Comment: You should try using the Maclaurin series expansion of $1/\sqrt{1+x^3},$ and then antidifferentiate the series expansion. You will have more success this way, since then you will be able to use the definition of the hypergeometric series in a straightforward way.

Comment: try with $u=\sqrt{x^3 +1}$ with this your integral is transformer $(u=\sec\theta)$ in $\int \tan^{\frac{1}{3}} \theta\sec \theta$

Comment: @Angel  This is the idea?  ibb.co/4YRkYPQ

Comment: @weymarandres This would end the same in a 2F1, what would be the advantage in making that substitution?

Comment: Note $\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^3}}dx$ is an elliptic integral, and cannot be written using elementary functions.  So it cannot be evaluated in closed form using the methods of a first course in integral calculus.

Comment: @strikar simen , sorry i do not know!!i hope all comments and answer worth for you

Comment: @weymarandres oh it's good, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$(1+x^3)^{-1/3}=1-\frac13x^3-\frac13\left(-\frac43\right)\frac{(x^3)^2}2-\frac13\left(-\frac43\right)\left(-\frac73\right)\frac{(x^3)^3}{3!}+\cdots$$ and after integration

$$x\left(1+\frac13\frac{(-x^3)}4+\frac13\frac43\frac{(-x^3)^2}{7\cdot2}+\frac13\frac43\frac73\frac{(-x^3)^3}{10\cdot3!}+\cdots\right)$$

Comment: This is a good solution, but maybe try writing it in $\sum_{n=a}^\infty A(n)$ form?

Comment: try taking the Angel approach, is that correct? How will it then obtain the values ​​$(b) _n$ and $(c) _n$ if it is correct https://ibb.co/4YRkYPQ

Comment: @TymaGaidash: it's the OP's task to find the matching between the given terms and the products met in the hypergeometric functions. I am flagging as a hint.

Comment: @Guste So, in your answer are the terms "hidden" to be able to arrive at the hypergeometric series? do you have any other example apart? at my university they never taught me series.

Comment: @Guste Investigating more I found the following, this can be the key to deduce the answer? a bionomial series and then compare to be able to generate 2F1? $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{\left(a\right)_n\left(b\right)_n}{\left(c\right)_n}\frac{z^n}{n!}=1\cdot \frac{z^0}{0!}+\frac{ab}{c}\cdot \frac{z^1}{1!}+\frac{a\left(a+1\right)b\left(b+1\right)}{c\left(c+1\right)}\cdot \frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{a\left(a+1\right)\left(a+2\right)b\left(b+1\right)\left(b+2\right)}{c\left(c+1\right)\left(c+2\right)}\cdot \frac{z^3}{3!}+...$

Comment: @Guste Hey it looks like I was finally able to get it this is my result $x\left(1+\frac{\frac{1}{2}\cdot \left(-x^3\right)^1}{4\cdot 1!}+\frac{\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}+1\right)\left(x^3\right)^2}{4\cdot 2!}+\frac{\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}+1\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}+2\right)\cdot \left(-x^3\right)^3}{4\cdot 3!}+\frac{\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}+1\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}+2\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}+3\right)\cdot \left(x^3\right)^4}{4\cdot 4!}+...\right)$

Comment: $x\left(1+\frac{\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{2}\cdot \left(-x^3\right)^1}{\frac{4}{3}\cdot 1!}+\frac{\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{3}+1\right)\cdot \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}+1\right)\cdot \left(x^3\right)^2}{\frac{4}{3}\left(\frac{4}{3}+1-1\right)\cdot 2!}+\frac{\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{3}+1\right)\left(\frac{1}{3}+2\right)\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}+1\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}+2\right)\cdot \left(-x^3\right)^3}{\frac{4}{3}\left(\frac{4}{3}+1-1\right)\left(\frac{4}{3}+2-1\right)\cdot 3!}+...\right)$

Comment: $\begin{array}{l}x\left(\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)_n\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_n}{\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)_n}\frac{\left(-x^3\right)^n}{n!}\right)\\
x_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2};\frac{4}{3};-x^3\right)+C\end{array}$